# Oracle: select from two tables

Tags: oracle10g

I have two tables `EMPLOYEE` and `DEPARTMENT`.

Columns of the `DEPARTMENT` table:

```
 DEPARTMENT_ID
 DEPARTMENT_NAME
 MANAGER_ID
 LOCATION_ID
```

Columns of `EMPLOYEE` table

```
EMPLOYEE_ID
FIRST_NAME
LAST_NAME
EMAIL
PHONE_NUMBER
HIRE_DATE DATE
JOB_ID
SALARY
COMMISSION_PCT
MANAGER_ID
DEPARTMENT_ID
```

When the desired number appears `DEPARTMENT_ID` chose `EMPLOYEE_ID`

```
FIRST_NAME
LAST_NAME
EMAIL
PHONE_NUMBER
HIRE_DATE DATE
JOB_ID
SALARY
COMMISSION_PCT
MANAGER_ID
DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Comment: 1) Pleace fix yer grammer sir!
2) So what is your question?

Comment: I want to show me all the existing fields in the Employees table when he chose DEPARTMENT_ID

Comment: so you need: select * from epmloyee where department_id = ?

Comment: Yup,Thankful you your efforts

Comment: department_id exists for both tables When I chose the No. Department your own fields shows me in the Employees table

Answer (score 1):

Please execute this query

```
select 
    emp.first_name, emp.last_name, emp.email, emp.phone_number, 
    dept.manager_id 
from 
    employee emp, department dept 
where 
    emp.department_id = dept.department_id
```

Comment: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: department_id exists for both tables
When I chose the No. Department your own fields shows me in the Employees table

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: select emp.first_name, emp.last_name,emp.email, emp.phone_number, dept.DEPARTMENT_ID=90
from EMPLOYEES emp, DEPARTMENTS dept where emp.department_id = dept.department_id